# Need to create a dropdownlist delimiters

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to create a list of delimiters which in the end need to be populated in the dropdown. The list should basically contain characters like

!, @,#,$,~,comma,;..etc.  . They should not be hardocoded though.

I have this already which is hardcoded but the client needs all the ascii delimiters now.

```
public SelectList Delimiters
    {
        get
        {
            var delims = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"None", string.Empty},
                {",", ","},
                {".", "."},
                {"/", "/"},
                {"#", "#"},
                {"|", "|"},
                {"Tab", "\t"}   
            };

            return new SelectList(delims, "Value", "Key");
        }
    }
```

How do we convert this to include all the special characters without hardcoding ?

Comment: What is the problem with hardcoding the delimiters? I doubt that there is a complete list somewhere in the framework because you can use every character or even string as delimiter.

Comment: Typing every special character is a bit of a task. So i felt there would be method to bring in all the delimiters at one go.

Comment: So apart from those above you want all other ascii characters as delimiter where the value equals the key?

Comment: Yes thats right..But not necessary value equals key...i just want all ascii special charcters...

Comment: I am referring to this link here..http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a complete list of all printable characters? Perhaps...

```
Dictionary<string, string> delims = 
    Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue - char.MinValue)
    .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(i))
    .Where(c => !Char.IsControl(c))
    .ToDictionary(c => c.ToString(), c => c.ToString());
```

The dictionary contains more than 65400 characters, if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However can we tweak this code only to bring in characters for 1st 128 characters...Please refer link http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table

Comment: @SandyW: yes, instead of `char.Maxvalue` use 128